# Does Cortana support webhooks / calling external API's?

Tags: c#, botframework, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-language-understanding, cortana

I've been trying out to create **skills for Cortana** and would like to hook it up to a **.NET Core web API** that I made. This web API already contains implementations for Google Home and Alexa and I would like to add Cortana communication to this web API.

Currently I've looked into the [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/skills/get-started) on the microsoft website and played around with them. The examples give me a .zip file with a pre-generated project which handles the requests, I would like to use my own web API for this.

When publishing apps in **LUIS** I found some info on endpoints under the **Keys and Endpoint settings**, but it doesn't seem to be a kind of endpoint that I'm looking for.

> Is it possible to use personal Web API's to handle intent behavior similar to [Dialogflow
>   webhooks](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment) or [Alexa Endpoints](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html) for Cortana bots?

Any links or other references would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no webhook functionality within the bot framework as is available in Assistant or Alexa projects, but you can invoke your API from within the bot's `OnTurnAsync` method - we do this for a Cortana implementation of our bot. Note that  as we do our own AI, we only receive the raw text, without any intent or entity parsing.

Comment: There is no reason why you can't call other APIs from botframework. And... you can also host your bot anywhere (as long as you use a bot channel registration). I am aware of a couple folks that built proxy bots to transform between bot service/cortana and other services.

Comment: And for one of my multi-agent bots - I wrote an agent agnostic service my action and skill talk to - you can play a game - with state - on Google Home or Invoke. Like Stuart mentioned - it just passes raw text and lets the service do the LU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a [Bot Channels Registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#create-a-bot-channels-registration), a `Cortana` connected skill will make POST calls to the configured `Messaging Endpoint`:

[image]

All Bot Framework services use industry-standard [REST and JSON over HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-overview) and communicate with messages based on the [Bot Framework -- Activity](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/specs/botframework-activity/botframework-activity.md) schema.  With the Cortana channel, when a POST is received at the Messaging Endpoint the code must acknowledge the call (HttpStatus 200) and send return messages within 10 seconds ([serviceUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#base-uri) is the base url for the destination).  Your code can call into whatever other services or apis you require during that time.

The [Bot Builder SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/) helps enable more easily communicating with Bot Framework services, including the [Cortana Connector Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-cortana?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).